# Как установить SDK manager в Android Stusio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-sdk, sdk

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста добавить SDK в Андроид Студио . Как и куда его нужно добавить ? Хэлп

Comment: а галку напротив sdk platform если поставить? по логике студия все сама ставить будет что ей не будет хватать

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать то, что выделено восклицательным знаком в красном кружке.

Comment: Галка не нажимается.
Локация в красном кружке неправильно указана. 
А как же ее указать правильно , если нету ничего скачанного из SDK ?

Comment: оно само качает sdk, вы ничего не навыбирали до этого экрана?

Comment: Я так понимаю SDK , это как драйвера которые нужно найти и установить. Я их скачал и распоковал , указываю поть к ним, но ничего не происходит.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-download-and-install-android-studio-in-windows-10/ вот есть инструкция, допускаю что у вас что-то не видится, ничего отдельно качать не нужно, оно само его скачает последней версии

Comment: ничего не выбирал

Comment: Не могу даже проект создать ! Пишет  You android sdk is missing

Comment: попробуйте снести студию, и заново поставить по какой-то инструкции, никаких путей к sdk создавать не нужно, оно все само должно подтянуть нормально

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать переустановить !  Скажите а имеет значение путь устанвки программы ? Если я ее не на диск С:  а на диск Д например установлю ?  Это ничего не поменяет  ?

Comment: по логике все должно быть нормально, главное не напутайте пути к sdk, а так то должно быть все нормально при стандартной установке

Comment: попробуйте не использовать в пути к SDK русские буквы и удостоверьтесь что у вас есть доступ как у пользователя к этой папке

Comment: Уже многое перепробовал 1)Переустановил винду с 10 Home на 10 PRO . 2)Включил виртуализацию 3)Добавил в виндовс и включил компонент Hyper-V . И до сих пор не могу в Android Studio запустить эмулятор. Выбмвает ошибку . Скидываю скрин. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: ibb.co/zs8f3n0
ibb.co/3pqQsx8

Answer (score 1):

Написано же "Your Android SDK location contains non-ASCII characters". В пути не должно быть кириллицы (C:\Users\ **Администратор**).

Comment: Хороший пример того, почему кирилицу не стоит использовать в системе

Comment: Спасибо , а как же поменять слово Администратор на Administrator ?

Comment: Имя учетной записи

Comment: https://ibb.co/DwDLJg2

Comment: Очень интересный момент , когда отключаю виртуализацию то в процессе пишется что включен Hyper  -  V  э

Comment: Но когда виртуализация включена  , то Hyper V пропадает

Comment: Да очень просто - создать нового пользователя.